# Mocking bash input for testing some code in c++

Tags: c++, testing, googletest

I'm new with Gtest on C++ and I'm having trouble with testing a function that require an input from the user from the bash. How could I mock the bash so that the function thinks that someone is writing on the bash?

Comment: Welcome at stackoverflow. Please read this before asking another question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Comment: Unrelated: @MarekR here's a list of shortcuts you may find helpful. `[ask]` expands to [ask]. reprex just showed up so it may or may not yet have a shortcut.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks good to know.

Comment: @MarekR Somehow I neglected to link the list. Genius am I. [Here's the list](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

make a separate test file that imports your function.

```
int func_to_test(int userinput);

int main() {
    func_to_test(0);
    func_to_test(99999);
    func_to_test(-1);

    ....
    return 0;
}
```

For further reading I would look into unit testing libraries/methodologies.